# Managing threads in a ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I would like to know once the thread is done processing something, is it better to put the thread back or to discard the thread?

Does ThreadPool uses a Queue internally to store Threads and give it to process which requests a thread?

I looked at C# impl of thread, source code, hard to understand it. I d like to know if there is a easier implementation to understand how thread pool works and internal details.

Comment: You should look @ ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkitem.  As the name implies, it's a queue of tasks to be preformed against a pool of threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if you should put the thread back in the pool or discard it you need to know your use of the thread pool.  For instance, is the cost of creating a new thread greater than managing it in the thread pool and it will be used in a timely manner, then keep it in the pool.  But I wouldn't keep it in the pool if it won't be used for 5 days.

Comment: Yeah, I agree @EstebanAraya, why quibble about a few threads lying around when you have GB's of RAM & virtual memory.  My Windows sidebar has 69 threads lying around for weeks, (current threads on my nearly idle system 1116).  It's just not a problem - worry about the real bugs!